# Intersection of lines in $ \mathbb{P}^3 $ can be given as zero locus of homogeneous linear polynomial in $ \mathbb{P}^5 $

Tags: algebraic-geometry, grassmannian

I'm currently stuck at Exercise 8.19 b) in the notes to Algebraic Geometry from  [Gathmann](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2014/alggeom-2014.pdf)

> Let $L \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ be an arbitrary line. Show that the set of lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$ that intersect $L$, considered as a subset of $G(2,4) \subset \mathbb{P}^5 $, is the zero locus of a homogeneous linear polynomial.

I tried solving the problem by first fixing a line in $\mathbb{P}^3$ and looking at all lines that intersect it and then derive the form of the needed linear homogeneous linear polynomial. But have no idea how.

So i started with fixing $L$ as $Lin(e_1 ,e_2) $ this leads to coordinate $(1:0:0:0:0:0)$ in $\mathbb{P}^5$ with Plücker embedding. Obviously the lines $(e_1,e_3),(e_1,e_4),(e_2,e_3),(e_2,e_4),(e_3,e_4)$ intersect $L$ and have coordinates $(0:1:0:0:0:0),...,(0:0:0:0:1:0)$.
Now i need to also include lines that are linear combinations of my basis vectors for example $(e_1+e_2,e_2+e_3)$. My question is how to find all of these lines and how to build a homogeneous linear polynomial from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L$ be the line given by the projectivization of the span of $e_1, e_2$. In other words, $L$ is the vanishing locus of $e_3$ and $e_4$. Let $v, w \in (\mathbb{C}^4)^*$ be linearly independent dual vectors (i.e., homogeneous linear forms, whose vanishing loci are planes), and let $L'$ be the line whose image in the Plucker embedding is given by $v \wedge w$ (i.e., $L'$ is the vanishing locus of the functionals $v,w$). Then $L \cap L'$ is nonempty precisely when there exists $[a : b ] \in \mathbb{P}^1$ such that $v(ae_1 + be_2) = w(ae_1 +be_2) = 0$. Let $v = \sum_{i = 1}^4 c_ie_i^*$ and $w = \sum_{i = 1}^4 d_ie_i^*$. Then $v(ae_1 + be_2) = w(ae_1 +be_2) = 0$ is equivalent to saying that $ac_1 + bc_2 = ad_1 + bd_2 = 0$, so $L \cap L'$ is nonempty precisely when the matrix $\left[\begin{array}{cc} c_1 & c_2 \\ d_1 & d_2\end{array}\right]$ has vanishing determinant, which occurs when $c_1d_2 - d_1c_2 = 0$. But the $e_1^* \wedge e_2^*$ coordinate of $v \wedge w$ is given by $c_1d_2 - d_1c_2$, so $L \cap L'$ is nonempty precisely when $L'$ has vanishing $e_1^* \wedge e_2^*$ coordinate under the Plucker embedding, and this is obviously a hyperplane condition on the $\mathbb{P}^5$ in which $G(2,4)$ sits.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering my question. Now i have two questions with regards two to answer. First im unfamiliar with the notation $e_i^*$ what is the difference to $e_i$. Second you wrote that $L \cap L' $ is nonempty when $e_1^* \land e_2^*$ vanished under the Plücker embedding. But $L \cap L$ is nonempty and $e_1 \land e_2 \neq 0 $ and would this not also mean that $L \cap (e_3 \land e_4) $ should have a nonempty intersection.

Comment: $e_i^*$ simply means the linear function $\mathbb{C}^4 \to \mathbb{C}$ that sends $e_i$ to $1$ and $e_j$ to $0$ for all $j \neq i$. The Plucker embedding sends a line in $\mathbb{P}^3$ defined as the vanishing locus of a pair of linear forms $v,w$ to the vector $v \wedge w$. I mean that $L \cap L'$ is nonempty when the coordinate of the basis vector $e_1^* \wedge e_2^*$ in $v \wedge w$ is $0$ (i.e., write $v \wedge w$ in the basis $\{e_i^* \wedge e_j^*: 1 \leq i < j \leq 4\}$, and the coefficient of $e_1^* \wedge e_2^*$ has to be $0$). I am not saying that $e_1 \wedge e_2 = 0$.

Comment: I try understand your explanation by running through it for fixed $ L = Lin(e_1,e_2) $ and $L' = Lin(e_1+e_4, e_2 -e_4) $ correct me if i go wrong somewhere. Then $ L\cap L' $ is nonempty when $v(ae_1+be_2)=w(ae_1+be_2)=0$
, in this case if i take as base for my dual space $\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\}$. This should be $ a = b = 0$ , but i should have something wrong here since $(0:0) \notin \mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: I think you may have mistakenly taken $v = e_1^* + e_4^*$ and $w = e_2^* - e_4^*$. In this case you ought to take, for example, $v = e_1^* - e_2^* - e_4^*$ and $w = e_3^*$, because you need $L'$ to be the intersection of the vanishing loci of $v$ and $w$. Note that with my choice of $v$ and $w$, you get $v(e_1 + e_4) = v(e_2 - e_4) = w(e_1 + e_4) = w(e_2 - e_4) = 0$. So $v(ae_1+be_2) = a-b$ and $w(ae_1+be_2) = 0$. So taking $a = b \neq 0$ works.

Comment: Sorry but i still dont get it. I will try another direction, can you explain why the intersection beeing nonempty is equivalent to the condition $v(ae_1+be_2)=w(ae_1+be_2)=0$ ? And if you say that $v,w \in (\mathbb{C}^4)^* $ are homoheneous linear forms, whose vanishing loci are planes. For $Lin(e_1,e_2)$ its obvious $V(e_3,e_4)$, but how do you compute this form for the case $Lin(e_1+e_4,e_2-e_4)$.

Comment: (1) Notice that every point on $\operatorname{Lin}(e_1, e_2)$ corresponds to a linear combination $ae_1 + be_2$, so for that point to lie on the line $L'$, it must be in the vanishing locus of both $v,w$, because the line $L'$ is defined to be the vanishing locus of $v$ and $w$. (2) You just need to choose any $2$ different homogeneous linear forms vanishing on both $e_1 + e_4$ and $e_2 - e_4$. After some playing around, I found the forms $v = e_1^* - e_2^* - e_4^*$ and $w = e_3^*$ in my previous comment.